# Use Ajax with jQuery UI in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-ui, jquery

Hello stakers
I wonder if it is possible to use ajax link with jQuery ui tools in Zend Framework :
I have a tabContainer, but all tabs content has to be given at creation time.. is there any simple way to use ajax for load only content in the selected pane ?

[EDIT]
I finally found it :

```
$this->tabPane(
    'MyTabGroup',
    '', // no content needed cause we're loading it with Ajax
    array(
        'title' => 'My link title',
        // here is the trick : contentUrl contains the url we want to load with Ajax
        'contentUrl' => $this->url(array(
                                         'module' => 'default',
                                         'controller' => 'declaration',
                                         'action' => 'consulter'
                                        )
                                  ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your UI Tabs plugin to load a URL instead of toggling the visibility of existing content?

If that's the case then you can check out the UI Tabs demo page for examples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

```
$('#example').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

UI Tab will now load the `<a>` href into the tab space using AJAX.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to do this with the ZendX jQuery helpers API, but maybe i'll be faster to write my own helper